# Create a Toolbar with Fade effect in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-menu

I have an activity with three tabs where each tab a different and for movement between the fragments fragment is displayed, use a `ViewPager`. I inflate fragments from the `Toolbar` the menu for each fragment.

The problem comes when I want the items that make up each menu appear (when the menu is displayed) with a fade effect and disappears with it (when switching to another fragment and the above fragment is destroyed).

With the effect of appearing, I have not had any problems. Implement it within the method `onCreateOptionsMenu ()` in the `FragmentInfoCenter.java` fragment and worked well, but not as realize the effect of disappearing just before the menu is destroyed.

I've gotten appears just like this:

[image: Effect menu item between fragments]

I tried to introduce this effect in `onDestroyOptionsMenu ()`, but I jump an error saying that the system can not access the menu item because it is null (obviously, as it is the menu that is being destroyed) and I have also tested implement the code in `onOptionsMenuClosed ()` method, but it is never not enter, that is, the system passes from him.

The code fragment `FragmentInfoCenter.java` where the action takes place is as follows:

```
public class FragmentInfoCenter extends Fragment {

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private Menu menuFade;
    private ImageView iv;

    public FragmentInfoCenter() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_info_center, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        drawerLayout = ((DrawerLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
        // Menu icon that want to apply the fade effect when it is created 
        // and when destroyed.
        iv = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_item_change, null);

        return view;
    }

    // Here I have tried to create the effect fade the menu item when 
    // appear, but I appear a telling exception that the menu item is null 
    // because it is already destroyed.
    @Override
    public void onDestroyOptionsMenu() {
        /*Animation fade_out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.fade_out);
        iv.startAnimation(fade_out);
        menuFade.findItem(R.id.option_change).setActionView(iv);*/
        super.onDestroyOptionsMenu();
    }


    // I have also tried to use this method, but the system never enter.
    @Override
    public void onOptionsMenuClosed(Menu menu) {
        super.onOptionsMenuClosed(menu);
        Animation fade_out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),  R.anim.fade_out);
        iv.startAnimation(fade_out);
        menu.findItem(R.id.option_change).setActionView(iv);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // Clean the menu, so that the menus do not accumulate
        if (menu != null) menu.clear();
        // Inflate the menu with the new
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.frag_menu_center, menu);
        // Add the animation icon iv declared in the onCreate() method
        //menuFade = menu;
        Animation fade_in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),     R.anim.fade_in);
        iv.startAnimation(fade_in);
        menu.findItem(R.id.option_change).setActionView(iv);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

The layout `menu_item_change.xml` I add a ImagenView called `iv`, which in the `onCreateOptionsMenu ()` method I add animation and `fade_id` menuItem will associate the `option_change`.

`Menu_item_change.xml` the layout is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:src="@drawable/change" />
```

The animation file `fade_in.xml` is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="1000" />
```

Along with the opposite `fade_out.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:toAlpha="0.0"
    android:duration="1000" />
```

These two files are in the `res/anim` folder.

Finally, the menu that I apply to this fragment is as follows (file `frag_menu_center.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/option_change"
        android:icon="@drawable/change"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/action_change" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/option_edit"
        android:icon="@drawable/edit"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/action_edit" />

</menu>
```

For more I look online, I find no method that can be run just before the destruction of the menu or there is very little information about it.

**I just want that when the `Tab 2` fragment change any other fragment, the icon of the arrows fade with fade effect** and I believe is amazing that we can not do.

**NOTE:** The example I've put (the three tabs) may be too long to put all the project code, so to make it clearer, I leave this [link](https://mega.nz/#!MIM1wIYJ!0nmCVjBPgYJ7VN1NU2icQe3HJRp633KXUZ927QJ7P5A) where can Unload the sample project, ready to export to Android Stuido and thus see more clearly what I get. The comments are in spanish, sorry.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your minSdkVersion ?

Comment: The minSdkVersion in API 17, equivalent to Android Jeally Bean 4.2.